Why are scaleWidth and scaleHeight unusually large in the canvg options?
My code snippet produces the output I want...well close.

However, I am struggling to understand why scaleWidth and scaleHeight needed to be 400.
My goal was to have the SVG drawn with a width & height of 40. I would have thought that I would set:
  preset.scaleWidth = 40;
  preset.scaleHeight = 40;

As the documentation for them say:
Scales horizontally to width.
Scales vertically to height.

The SVG is ~44 pixels in width and height.
How can I better understand these properties so I can have the SVG drawn with a width and height of 40?


const svg = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#ff0000" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><!--!Font Awesome Free 6.7.2 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2024 Fonticons, Inc.--><path d="M256 0c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32l0 10.4c93.7 13.9 167.7 88 181.6 181.6l10.4 0c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32s-14.3 32-32 32l-10.4 0c-13.9 93.7-88 167.7-181.6 181.6l0 10.4c0 17.7-14.3 32-32 32s-32-14.3-32-32l0-10.4C130.3 455.7 56.3 381.7 42.4 288L32 288c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32s14.3-32 32-32l10.4 0C56.3 130.3 130.3 56.3 224 42.4L224 32c0-17.7 14.3-32 32-32zM107.4 288c12.5 58.3 58.4 104.1 116.6 116.6l0-20.6c0-17.7 14.3-32 32-32s32 14.3 32 32l0 20.6c58.3-12.5 104.1-58.4 116.6-116.6L384 288c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32s14.3-32 32-32l20.6 0C392.1 165.7 346.3 119.9 288 107.4l0 20.6c0 17.7-14.3 32-32 32s-32-14.3-32-32l0-20.6C165.7 119.9 119.9 165.7 107.4 224l20.6 0c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32s-14.3 32-32 32l-20.6 0zM256 224a32 32 0 1 1 0 64 32 32 0 1 1 0-64z"/></svg>`;

var blob = new Blob(
  Array.prototype.map.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('script[type="text/js-worker"]'),
    function (oScript) {
      return oScript.textContent;
    }
  ),
  { type: "text/javascript" }
);

const worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob), {
  type: "module"
});

const img = document.querySelector("img");

worker.postMessage({svg: svg});

worker.onmessage = (event) => {
  img.src = event.data.pngUrl;
};
<script type="text/js-worker">
  import { DOMParser } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/@xmldom/xmldom@^0.7.5'
  import {
    Canvg,
    presets
  } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/canvg@^4.0.0'

  const preset = presets.offscreen({
    DOMParser
  })

  preset.ignoreClear = true;
  preset.scaleWidth = 400;
  preset.scaleHeight = 400;
  
  self.onmessage = async (event) => {
    const { svg } = event.data;
    
    const radius = 28;
    const canvas = new OffscreenCanvas( radius * 2, radius * 2 ); // width, height
    const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(radius, radius, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fill();
    
    const v = await Canvg.from(ctx, svg, preset)
    await v.render()

    const blob = await canvas.convertToBlob()
    const pngUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)

    self.postMessage({
      pngUrl
    })
  }
</script>

<img />




Actually, your SVG dimensions are 512x512 units as specified in the viewBox attribute.
So preset.scaleWidth=400 would translate to a scaling factor of 0.78125


const svg = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#ff0000" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><!--!Font Awesome Free 6.7.2 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2024 Fonticons, Inc.--><path d="M256 0c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32l0 10.4c93.7 13.9 167.7 88 181.6 181.6l10.4 0c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32s-14.3 32-32 32l-10.4 0c-13.9 93.7-88 167.7-181.6 181.6l0 10.4c0 17.7-14.3 32-32 32s-32-14.3-32-32l0-10.4C130.3 455.7 56.3 381.7 42.4 288L32 288c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32s14.3-32 32-32l10.4 0C56.3 130.3 130.3 56.3 224 42.4L224 32c0-17.7 14.3-32 32-32zM107.4 288c12.5 58.3 58.4 104.1 116.6 116.6l0-20.6c0-17.7 14.3-32 32-32s32 14.3 32 32l0 20.6c58.3-12.5 104.1-58.4 116.6-116.6L384 288c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32s14.3-32 32-32l20.6 0C392.1 165.7 346.3 119.9 288 107.4l0 20.6c0 17.7-14.3 32-32 32s-32-14.3-32-32l0-20.6C165.7 119.9 119.9 165.7 107.4 224l20.6 0c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32s-14.3 32-32 32l-20.6 0zM256 224a32 32 0 1 1 0 64 32 32 0 1 1 0-64z"/></svg>`;

var blob = new Blob(
  Array.prototype.map.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('script[type="text/js-worker"]'),
    function (oScript) {
      return oScript.textContent;
    }
  ),
  { type: "text/javascript" }
);

const worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob), {
  type: "module"
});

const img = document.querySelector("img");

worker.postMessage({svg: svg});

worker.onmessage = (event) => {
  img.src = event.data.pngUrl;
};
<script type="text/js-worker">
  import { DOMParser } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/@xmldom/xmldom@^0.7.5'
  import {
    Canvg,
    presets
  } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/canvg@^4.0.0'

  const preset = presets.offscreen({
    DOMParser
  })
  

  // intrinsic dimensions from the SVG viewBox
  const svgW=512, svgH = 512
  const svgScale=0.75;
  
  preset.ignoreClear = true;
  preset.scaleWidth = svgW*svgScale;
  preset.scaleHeight = svgH*svgScale;
  
  self.onmessage = async (event) => {
    const { svg } = event.data;
    
    const radius = 20;
    const canvas = new OffscreenCanvas( radius * 2, radius * 2 ); // width, height
    const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(radius, radius, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fill();
    
    const v = await Canvg.from(ctx, svg, preset)
    await v.render()

    const blob = await canvas.convertToBlob()
    const pngUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)

    self.postMessage({
      pngUrl
    })
  }
</script>

<img />



See also working codepen
Here's also an example drawing the SVG on a native canvas.


let svg = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#ff0000" width="320" height="320" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M256 0c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32l0 10.4c93.7 13.9 167.7 88 181.6 181.6l10.4 0c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32s-14.3 32-32 32l-10.4 0c-13.9 93.7-88 167.7-181.6 181.6l0 10.4c0 17.7-14.3 32-32 32s-32-14.3-32-32l0-10.4C130.3 455.7 56.3 381.7 42.4 288L32 288c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32s14.3-32 32-32l10.4 0C56.3 130.3 130.3 56.3 224 42.4L224 32c0-17.7 14.3-32 32-32zM107.4 288c12.5 58.3 58.4 104.1 116.6 116.6l0-20.6c0-17.7 14.3-32 32-32s32 14.3 32 32l0 20.6c58.3-12.5 104.1-58.4 116.6-116.6L384 288c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32s14.3-32 32-32l20.6 0C392.1 165.7 346.3 119.9 288 107.4l0 20.6c0 17.7-14.3 32-32 32s-32-14.3-32-32l0-20.6C165.7 119.9 119.9 165.7 107.4 224l20.6 0c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32s-14.3 32-32 32l-20.6 0zM256 224a32 32 0 1 1 0 64 32 32 0 1 1 0-64z"/></svg>`;

(async () => {

  //desired width and height
  let width = 40;
  let height = 40;

  // set canvas dimensions
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;

  // manual scale for SVG graphic
  let svgScale = 0.75;


  // parse to retrieve viewBox
  let svgEl = new DOMParser()
    .parseFromString(svg, "image/svg+xml")
    .querySelector("svg");

  // prefer viewBox - otherwise take width and height attributes
  let w = svgEl.viewBox.baseVal?.width || (svgEl.width.baseVal?.value || 300);
  let h = svgEl.viewBox.baseVal?.height || (svgEl.height.baseVal?.value || 150);


  // draw SVG on canvas
  let blob = new Blob([svg], {
    type: "image/svg+xml"
  });
  let blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  let tmpImg = new Image();
  tmpImg.src = blobURL;
  tmpImg.width = w;
  tmpImg.height = h;
  tmpImg.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

  await tmpImg.decode();
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  let radius = width / 2
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(radius, radius, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.fill();

  // calculate offsets to center SVG
  let offsetX = (width - width * svgScale) / 2
  let offsetY = (height - height * svgScale) / 2

  // scale SVG to desired dimensions and draw
  ctx.drawImage(tmpImg, offsetX, offsetY, width * svgScale, height * svgScale);
})();
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>




How does the scale factor of 384 ( = 512 * .75) end up being 40pixels when rendered? It is that step that I am not understanding.

Frankly I'm not familiar with the internal calculation logics of canvg. But from the results it obviously scales a SVG to a specified width via preset.scaleWidth while using the center as a transform origin and draws this SVG to the desired canvas width/height (40 or r*2). So 384 is a scaled width and not a scaling factor

The scaleWidth and scaleHeight options will scale whatever the source size of the SVG image, to these; but it will still apply the default scaling to target.
So in your case, it will use the 56px canvas size as target size. If you want to target 40px inside that 56px canvas, you need to apply this 40 / 56 factor on the "unsized" SVG (512x512). And we end up with a target size of 365.7, close enough to your 400.


const svg = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#ff0000" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><!--!Font Awesome Free 6.7.2 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2024 Fonticons, Inc.--><path d="M256 0c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32l0 10.4c93.7 13.9 167.7 88 181.6 181.6l10.4 0c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32s-14.3 32-32 32l-10.4 0c-13.9 93.7-88 167.7-181.6 181.6l0 10.4c0 17.7-14.3 32-32 32s-32-14.3-32-32l0-10.4C130.3 455.7 56.3 381.7 42.4 288L32 288c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32s14.3-32 32-32l10.4 0C56.3 130.3 130.3 56.3 224 42.4L224 32c0-17.7 14.3-32 32-32zM107.4 288c12.5 58.3 58.4 104.1 116.6 116.6l0-20.6c0-17.7 14.3-32 32-32s32 14.3 32 32l0 20.6c58.3-12.5 104.1-58.4 116.6-116.6L384 288c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32s14.3-32 32-32l20.6 0C392.1 165.7 346.3 119.9 288 107.4l0 20.6c0 17.7-14.3 32-32 32s-32-14.3-32-32l0-20.6C165.7 119.9 119.9 165.7 107.4 224l20.6 0c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32s-14.3 32-32 32l-20.6 0zM256 224a32 32 0 1 1 0 64 32 32 0 1 1 0-64z"/></svg>`;

var blob = new Blob(
  Array.prototype.map.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('script[type="text/js-worker"]'),
    function (oScript) {
      return oScript.textContent;
    }
  ),
  { type: "text/javascript" }
);

const worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob), {
  type: "module"
});

const img = document.querySelector("img");

worker.postMessage({svg: svg});

worker.onmessage = (event) => {
  img.src = event.data.pngUrl;
};
<script type="text/js-worker">
  import { DOMParser } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/@xmldom/xmldom@^0.7.5'
  import {
    Canvg,
    presets
  } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/canvg@^4.0.0'

  const preset = presets.offscreen({
    DOMParser
  })
  preset.ignoreClear = true;
  
  self.onmessage = async (event) => {
    const { svg } = event.data;
    
    const radius = 28;
    const canvas = new OffscreenCanvas( radius * 2, radius * 2 ); // width, height
    const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
    const targetDimension = 40;
    const scaleFactor = targetDimension / canvas.width;
    const sourceDimension = 512;
    preset.scaleWidth = preset.scaleHeight = sourceDimension * scaleFactor;
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(radius, radius, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeRect(8, 8, 40, 40); // To check our dimensions are correct
    const v = await Canvg.from(ctx, svg, preset)
    await v.render()

    const blob = await canvas.convertToBlob()
    const pngUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)

    self.postMessage({
      pngUrl
    })
  }
</script>

<img />



Alternatively, you could set the width and height attributes in your SVG markup, and then set the ignoreDimensions option so that canvg doesn't resize to the target canvas, and use the offsetX and offsetY ones to place it where you need:


const svg = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#ff0000" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="40" height="40" ><!--!Font Awesome Free 6.7.2 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2024 Fonticons, Inc.--><path d="M256 0c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32l0 10.4c93.7 13.9 167.7 88 181.6 181.6l10.4 0c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32s-14.3 32-32 32l-10.4 0c-13.9 93.7-88 167.7-181.6 181.6l0 10.4c0 17.7-14.3 32-32 32s-32-14.3-32-32l0-10.4C130.3 455.7 56.3 381.7 42.4 288L32 288c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32s14.3-32 32-32l10.4 0C56.3 130.3 130.3 56.3 224 42.4L224 32c0-17.7 14.3-32 32-32zM107.4 288c12.5 58.3 58.4 104.1 116.6 116.6l0-20.6c0-17.7 14.3-32 32-32s32 14.3 32 32l0 20.6c58.3-12.5 104.1-58.4 116.6-116.6L384 288c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32s14.3-32 32-32l20.6 0C392.1 165.7 346.3 119.9 288 107.4l0 20.6c0 17.7-14.3 32-32 32s-32-14.3-32-32l0-20.6C165.7 119.9 119.9 165.7 107.4 224l20.6 0c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32s-14.3 32-32 32l-20.6 0zM256 224a32 32 0 1 1 0 64 32 32 0 1 1 0-64z"/></svg>`;

var blob = new Blob(
  Array.prototype.map.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('script[type="text/js-worker"]'),
    function (oScript) {
      return oScript.textContent;
    }
  ),
  { type: "text/javascript" }
);

const worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob), {
  type: "module"
});

const img = document.querySelector("img");

worker.postMessage({svg: svg});

worker.onmessage = (event) => {
  img.src = event.data.pngUrl;
};
<script type="text/js-worker">
  import { DOMParser } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/@xmldom/xmldom@^0.7.5'
  import {
    Canvg,
    presets
  } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/canvg@^4.0.0'

  const preset = {
    ...presets.offscreen({ DOMParser }),
    ignoreClear: true,
    ignoreDimensions: true,
    offsetX: 8,
    offsetY: 8,
  };
  
  self.onmessage = async (event) => {
    const { svg } = event.data;
    const radius = 28;
    const canvas = new OffscreenCanvas( radius * 2, radius * 2 ); // width, height
    const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(radius, radius, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeRect(8, 8, 40, 40); // To check our dimensions are correct
    const v = await Canvg.from(ctx, svg, preset)
    await v.render()

    const blob = await canvas.convertToBlob()
    const pngUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)

    self.postMessage({
      pngUrl
    })
  }
</script>

<img />



